# How to select element which is not 'this'?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have list of divs all with the same class, I want to apply a function to all of them which are not the clicked one (`this`), how can i select `!this` with jQuery?

UPDATE:
I've made this and it is not working, any ideas why?

```
    $("li").each(function(){
        $("li").not(this).click(function(e) {
            $(this).hide();
        });
    });
```

UPDATE 2: this is the whole actual code:

```
$(".mark").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var id = "#" + $(this).parent().parent().parent().parent().attr("id") + " ";

    var currentStatus = "deleted"; // to be replaced with actual status
    var currentStatusClass = "." + currentStatus + "-heading";
    $(id + currentStatusClass).show();

    $(id + ".edit-headings").click(function(){
        $(this).find(".headings-status").show().addClass("bg-hover");

        $(id + ".headings-status").click(function() {
            $(id + ".headings-status").not(this).hide();
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: it's not working cause you are saying: `LI(each) but not LI --> hide`

Comment: is `this` here includes all the `li` elements? not just the clicked one? how else then i can get only to the clicked `li`?

Comment: it's not relevant, i removed it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the [`.not()`](http://api.jquery.com/not/) function:

```
$('.yourclass').click(function() {
    $('.yourclass').not(this).yourFunc();
});
```

Answer (score 7):

Have a look at jQuerys `not` function: http://api.jquery.com/not/

```
$('div').not(this).doSomething();
```

Regarding your update, try:

```
        $("li").click(function(e) {
            $("li").not(this).hide();
        });
```

Comment: I am using a class name instead of `li` and it is not working, any idea why?

Comment: could you post your actual code please? remember to put a dot `.` before the classname when using them via jquery (i.e. `$('.myClass')`).

Answer (score 1):

use `$('div').not(this)` to select other than clicked one.

Answer (score 0):

using `:not()` or `.not()`

```
$this;

function myFunction(){
      // stuff here // and use $this for element reference
}


$('yourElement:not(.selected)').on('click',function(){
    // (make sure to add '.selected' to the new one and toggle existant)
    $('.selected').removeClass('selected');
    $this = $(this);
    $this.addClass('selected');

    myFunction();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

this is wrong:

```
var newStatus = $(this).className().replace("contribution-", "");
```

`className` is not a function.

Instead of above line you can try this:

```
var cls = $(this).attr('class').replace('contribution-','');
$(this).removeClass().addClass(cls);
```